# A binary BBP-type formula for log(23)

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, harmonic-numbers

This question is related to [Is there a binary spigot algorithm for log(23) or log(89)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42273/is-there-a-binary-spigot-algorithm-for-log23-or-log89) by Dan Brumleve.

A binary BBP-type formula is a convergent series formula of the type
$$
\alpha=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{p(k)}{2^kq(k)}
$$
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BBP-TypeFormula.html

The first prime for which it is not known whether such a formula exists is $23$.
http://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/digits.pdf, http://oeis.org/A104885

A conditionally convergent formula for $log(n)$ is given by the generalized Mercator series

$$
log\left(n\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=nk+1}^{n(k+1)}\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)
$$
[Do these series converge to logarithms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46378/do-these-series-converge-to-logarithms), [Series for logarithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883348/series-for-logarithms)

For odd arguments such as $23$, partial sums are closer to the limit if the following regrouping is chosen

$$
log(2n+1)=H_n+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=-n}^{n}\frac{1}{(2n+1)k+i}-\frac{1}{k}\right)
$$

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1602945/134791

Setting $n=11$ above,
$$
log(23)=H_{11}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=-11}^{11}\frac{1}{(2n+1)k+i}-\frac{1}{k}\right)
$$

Series acceleration allows to obtain the binary BBP-type formula for $log(2)$ from Mercator series.

Q: How can a BBP-type formula for $log(23)$ be obtained through acceleration of the corresponding conditionally convergent series?